# tableView.reloadData() and DispatchQueue not working to reload tableview in different view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have two view controllers, one with a table view (first VC) and a second one that can be navigated to via a button in the navigation bar. The second view controller is supposed to be able to add a table view cell into the tableview of the first view controller.

First View Controller:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
let tableView = UITableView()
var data = ["mars", "earth", "jupiter", "venus", "saturn"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    view.addSubview(tableView)
    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
}
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    tableView.frame = view.bounds
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return data.count
}
    
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

Second View Controller:

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var button: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var addPostButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    title = "Second Screen"
    
    
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

@IBAction func didTapButton(){
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    picker.allowsEditing = true
    picker.delegate = self
    present(picker, animated: true)
}

@IBAction func didTapAddPostButton(){
    let FVC = FirstViewController()
    FVC.data.append("New data added!")
    DispatchQueue.main.async{
    FVC.tableView.beginUpdates()
    FVC.tableView.performBatchUpdates({
            FVC.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: FVC.data.count - 1,
                                                     section: 0)],
                                      with: .automatic)
        }, completion: nil)
    FVC.tableView.endUpdates()
    }
    print("TapAddPostButton pressed")
    print(FVC.data)
}

}

extension SecondViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        
        guard let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage else {
            return
        }
        imageView.image = image
    }
}
```

**What's supposed to happen:** upon pressed the button in the second view controller, a new table cell is supposed to be added and then the tableview reloaded.

**What's actually happening:** the tableview is not being reloaded. When i swipe back to the first view controller, the tableview is the same as before and has not reloaded and updated with the new cell.

**Images:**

[This is the first view controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxSRn.png)

[This is the second view controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTzyg.png)

Comment: can you add images declaring the issue ??

Comment: I've added the images @Menaim

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but both `beginUpdates/endUpdates` and `performBatchUpdates`are pointless for a single insert operation. Apart from that both forms are synonyms.

Comment: check my updated answer, I think it will solve the issue

Answer (score 2):

When you do:

```
let FVC = FirstViewController()
```

... you're creating a new, unrelated instance of `FirstViewController`. This won't work. Look into [delegates + protocols](https://learnappmaking.com/delegation-swift-how-to/) or [closures](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html) (or show code for where you are presenting `SecondViewController` and I'll update my answer).

Comment: I've updated my post to include the code where I'm presenting the SecondViewController

Comment: it's in the main post under "second view controller"

Comment: @Hilardy ah I meant the place where you *present* the SecondViewController. Most likely inside `didSelectIndexAt`.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to achieve it, it's better to use protocols to be able to link these two `viewControllers` in the correct way.

Creating a protocol In anywhere you need:

```
protocol PassingProtocol {
func saveData(withText myText: String)
```

}

then in `FirstViewController`:

```
extension FirstViewController: PassingProtocol {
     func saveData(withText myText: String) {
       data.append(myText)
       DispatchQueue.main.async {
           self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
   }
```

In the Action of `NewEntry` `Barbutton` :

```
let myVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
    myVC.textDelegate = self
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(myVC, animated: true)
    
}
```

In the `SecondViewController`:

```
var textDelegate: PassingProtocol!
```

Then in the action of `didTapAddPostButton` :

```
textDelegate.saveData(withText: "New data added!")
```

If you need to use outlets follow the below steps:

FirstViewController.Swift:

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    var data = ["mars", "earth", "jupiter", "venus", "saturn"]

    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewOutlet: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



}
    
    @IBAction func newEntryAction(_ sender: Any) {
        let myVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
            myVC.textDelegate = self
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(myVC, animated: true)
            
        }
    }
    


extension FirstViewController : UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        data.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableViewOutlet.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell") as! MyCell
        cell.lblData.text = data[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    
    
}
extension FirstViewController: PassingProtocol {
     func saveData(withText myText: String) {
       data.append(myText)
       DispatchQueue.main.async {
           self.tableViewOutlet.reloadData()
        }
   }

}
```

SecondViewController.Swift

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textFieldData: UITextField!
    var textDelegate: PassingProtocol!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    

    @IBAction func addEntryButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
        textDelegate.saveData(withText: textFieldData.text!)

    }

}
```

PassingProtocol.Swift

```
import Foundation

    protocol PassingProtocol {
    func saveData(withText myText: String)
    }
```

MyCell.Swift

```
import UIKit

class MyCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var lblData: UILabel!

}
```

It will works , I've tried it myself and worked fine

Comment: Just finished implementing it. I received the error `Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value: file SecondViewController.swift, line 34` Line 34 is the textDelegate.saveData()

Comment: I will modify it now

Comment: Check the new solution @Hilardy

Comment: I am getting the error `Cannot find type 'PassingProtocol' in scope` in SecondViewController

Comment: create it, I've mentioned this in the solution and created it already in the solution

Answer (score 0):

After taking photo from a gallery. pass a delegate function to FirstVC.
FirstVC - function contain the data and Data count. Load Tableview in a dispatch queue method.